# Error on installing Git

Tags: centos, yum, git

I keep getting these errors when I try to install git:

```
Error: Package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.i386 (epel)
           Requires: libcurl.so.3
Error: Package: perl-Git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.i386 (epel)
           Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8)
```

I am not sure what is going on and what is wrong, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Server:

```
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
cpe:/o:centos:linux:6:GA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have the EPEL repository for RHEL / CentOS 5.x configured, not the EPEL repository for CentOS 6.x.  The 'el5' on the package name is a dead giveaway.

CentOS 6 ships with git in its' own repository.  The version number is lower than the one in the version 5.x repository which is causing yum to try to install that one instead.

I'd suggest two things:

- Try `yum --disablerepo=epel install git`.
- Remove the yum configuration for the EPEL 5 repository and install the configuration for EPEL 6 if you need packages from EPEL.  [EPEL / How can I use these extra packages](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL#How_can_I_use_these_extra_packages.3F)

Comment: That fixed it! thank you very much! I spent hours on this today! I am still working on learning Linux. I would upvote too, but not enough rep.

Comment: Ok, now how do I remove the old Git? It is causing problems with some software I am trying to use

Comment: Do you mean the one you just installed here with yum?  If yes, `yum erase git`, `yum remove git` would work as well.  `man yum` will give you all the details for using yum.  If you mean another copy, I'd have to know how you installed it.  The original EL5/EPEL. version shouldn't be installed (due to the errors).